# Need input on using Camunda workflow for handling country specific flows

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, bpmn, camunda, zeebe

We have a created an application that was developed addressing the flow for a specific country/region. Now we are thinking of extending the application to other countries/region. There are certain flows which will be common and certain flows will be different for each country/region

Lets say the customer onboarding flow for India will require set of documents that will be verified against 3rd party API for verification/validation. Where as the customer onboarding will require different set of documents and some additional data for another country where it will be verified against different 3rd party APIs.

Is it advisable to create workflows for each country which will have the human tasks to capture the necessary data and external tasks/HTTP connector to interact with 3rd party API

Please suggest whether to go for workflow based solution or suggest any other solution that will be suitable to support multiple countries flow

The application is built on spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Before concluding on the approach, let's first collect and analyze the supporting info:

1. Business-wise, will you be tracking country-level cases independently or it's a part of the same flow?
2. Will the country-specific flow be triggered during the start of the flow?
3. If routed to the country-specific flow, is there a possibility of triggering a stage that is a part of common flow?

Comment: 1. Different workflow for each of the country
2. Yes 
3. The plan is to have a common service that will take care of triggering the workflows. The tasks in workflow will invoke the region specific services to complete the task. There are common tasks like persisting data to databases, Error scenarios and those will be handled the common services

Common services - responsible for triggering the workflow and taking care of common activities across regions like data persistence, etc.
Region services - responsible for provide region specific funtionalities to complete the task

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this definitely remains a good use case for process management / workflow.

Consider structuring your end-to end process into a parent process which contains generic parts and different sub processes which cover the country specific variants. The call activity you use in the parent process to reference the sub process can use an expression for the process name. This allows you to dynamically determine the applicable sub process as runtime, e.g. based on a data containing the country code.